# Reflections on a unit test looking for generics in an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I want to write some unit tests to make sure my domain namespace and my `IUnitOfWork` interface are properly synced.

For example, if I have a domain entity of `Foo`, I should have a corresponding property of type IQueryable in my IUnitOfWork interface.  So if I have:

```
namespace My.Domain 
{
    public class Foo : IEntity<Guid>
    {
        //properties
    }
}

namespace My.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        public IQueryable<Foo> Foos { get; }
    }
}
```

I started my unit test like so:

```
private static readonly Assembly _assembly = typeof(Assembly.Class).Assembly;

[TestMethod]
public void AllEntitiesInNamespaceHaveCorrespondingIUnitOfWorkProperties()
{
    var classesInDomainNamespace = _assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Namespace, "My.Domain", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .Distinct();

    var entitiesInUnitOfWork = typeof(IUnitOfWork).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable<IEntity<Guid>>)))
        .Distinct();
}
```

...and this is where I started to run into problems.  Ideally, I want to assert the number of records in `classesInDomainNamespace` and `entitiesInUnitOfWork` were the same, but things get weird when dealing with generics.

How would I write this unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?:

```
var entitiesInUnitOfWork = typeof(IUnitOfWork).GetProperties()
    .Where(x => 
        x.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
        x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>) &&  
        typeof(IEntity<Guid>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .Distinct();
```

This is not testet. Not even compiled - but I hope it gives the correct hint.